# Apache Reverse Proxy configuration - Subdomains

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I am trying to configure an Apache server to have 2 subdomains making use of a reverse proxy. I am able to redirect traffic to the first subdomain (first.example.com) and retrieve content from the https site successfully. However, whenever I try to access the second subdomain I end up getting content from the first, and since routes don't match my local website, I get a not found page.

I would like to know what can I adjust from my current configuration so I can get content from my localhost site to.

Here is my current configuration:

```
<Proxy *>
Require all granted
</Proxy>

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLInsecureRenegotiation on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

<VirtualHost first.example.com:80>
    ServerName first.example.com
    ProxyPass /first https://stackoverflow.com
    ProxyPassReverse /first https://stackoverflow.com
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ https://stackoverflow.com/$1

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost second.example.com:80>
    ServerName second.example.com
    ProxyPass /site http://localhost/site
    ProxyPassReverse /site http://localhost/site
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://localhost/site/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Best Regards!

Edgar Martínez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current configuration is conflicting with itself. [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [ProxyPassMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) does the same thing (in regex) but you declared it both with different rules.

```
ProxyPass /site http://localhost/site
```

Rule says: anyone that visits `http://second.example.com/site` will be fed content from `http://localhost/site`. If you visit `http://second.example.com/foo`, you get nothing.

The match line

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://localhost/site/$1
```

Rule says: Anyone that visits `http://second.example.com/site` will be fed content from `http://localhost/site/site`. If you visit `http://second.example.com/foo`, you get `http://localhost/site/foo`.

If you use the Match version (regex), you're also out of luck for the reverse rule which doesn't have a regex version. Though, I'm not certain you actually need the reverse rule.

As to why your second request got result from the first... I have no idea.

Comment: Hello @Grumpy, 

You were right, my config was conflicting with itself.

This is how I changed it:

`NameVirtualHost *:80`

`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`ServerName first.example.com`
`DocumentRoot "F:/root/htmldocs"`
`</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`ProxyPreserveHost on`
`ServerName second.example.com`
`ProxyPass "/" "https://stackoverflow.com/"`
`ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://stackoverflow.com/"`
`</VirtualHost>`


Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.